# How can I convert WebRTC audio stream into a shareable audio stream URL?

Tags: streaming, webrtc, audio-streaming

I am using Chrome's tabCapture API (see https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabCapture) to capture an audio stream from the currently-active tab in Chrome. This creates a MediaStream object (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Media_Streams_API) populated with data, for example, I can pull this info from Chrome's console:

```
MediaStream {id: "qih5TZY7OTyNnydtEQ4IwK3FSFiaYhz54TeG", active: true, onactive: null, oninactive: null, onaddtrack: null…}
active: true
id: "qih5TZY7OTyNnydtEQ4IwK3FSFiaYhz54TeG"
onactive: null
onaddtrack: null
onended: function()
oninactive: null
onremovetrack: null
__proto__: MediaStream
```

How can I manipulate this MediaStream into a streaming audio url which I can pass to another application / browser to tune into, similar to a streaming radio service?

Can I use something like URL.createObjectUrl(my-media-stream) ?

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL

Do I need to convert into using a websocket instead of webRTC?

Can I use Socket.io?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A `stream` is a local resource here. `createObjectURL` is just a hack to refer to it by URL locally.

If you want to transport this data to a server where it can be staged behind a permanent URL for broadcast, then you have work to do.

**Update:** If you want to send a stream to another machine, you could establish an RTCPeerConnection to the other machine, and send the stream that way.

Comment: Ok, thanks. It's possible a local URL will be good enough, since I actually just want to transfer a stream within the local network. (A global URL is a nice-to-have, but I'll settle for local for now).

So using createObjectUrl will let me make a local URL at least? I'll investigate.

Comment: @nyarasha no, I mean local to the machine. To send a stream to another machine, you could establish an RTCPeerConnection.

Comment: Right, that's if the connecting device has a browser that can use WebRTC. In this case, I want to send a stream to a device that does not have a web browser. Thanks though.